# Why is a condition in IF/AND statement being overlooked

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following formula in place.

```
=TRIM(
IFERROR(IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase",$T9<>""),Key!$L$11,""),"Error")
)
```

I was noticing that the "Error" part of the `IFERROR` was running. So after reviewing my formula, I was pretty certain the reason was that column T was empty sometimes. So I put the following check into place `$T9<>""`. However, since adding this, the "Error" is still showing.

Shouldn't my added condition result in the "FALSE" part of the condition running? Which is just "".

Does anyone have any insight?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you find **a blank cell** to test the formula `IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete" ,$G9<>"New Phase"),Key!$L$11,"")` and check its result. I simulated an example based on your description, if T9 is empty, the formula is empty. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKA7C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is no construction failure with your formula, so the problem is not due to that cause. As written, it works, logically, so the failure to produce must be due to either the use functions and such are put to, or the values which they use.

By "the use functions... are put to" I mean that sometimes the formation of a use causes problems due to intermediate steps one might not think of. For instance, to use a fake example, "fake" because it isn't really a thing that would cause a problem (but no real example jumps to mind), let's say the problem was in subtracting `TODAY()` from a value and then comparing that to some other value. Like:

```
=$T9 - TODAY() <= Key!$M$14
```

Pretend that Excel would error if the left half produced a negative value during the evaluation of this formula. (It does NOT because Excel does not do any "type" consideration when processing, so it does not expect a date result and so it does not error if a negative value results. But pretend.) So Excel would get that negative as its first step in evaluating the formula and error right then, not going forward. It would carry that error to each later calculation and so the final result inside the `IFERROR()` would be an error and get you that result.

(Again, this is pretend. But as an example of how you could quickly overcome that, you might just simply algebraically move the `TODAY()` to the right side where it presumably would be added to a positive value, so when evaluated it could never give an interim result that is negative so never trigger an error. Once evaluated, the right side would lose the date aspect, being just a number, and all the funny business would be over. So simple fixes are often available.)

As I say, that is NOT a problem with any component of your formula. So now you are left with the only real possibility:  `some component (cell) used in one of the` AND() `components contains an error`.

This is irrespective of whether, for example, you really want `Key!$M$9` not `Key!$M$14` or `T14` not `T9` or any consideration of that kind. *(Except in an indirect way:  If there is a mis-choiced member of the formula, say the `T9` needing to be `T14` AND `T9` happens to have an error in it while `T14` does not.)*

So pick a use of the formula that powers up the `IFERROR()` rather than evaluating successfully and look at each of the cells referenced in it. A good, quick way to do that is to copy out the formula in one of the cells that gives `Error` (press F2, highlight everything and Copy, then go to some empty space somewhere so you can work without damaging anything and press F2 and Paste — formula will have the exact same references as where you got it from dies). Then, in the cells below the formula, put `=` and each cell reference. So:

```
=T9
=Key!$n$14
```

and so on. Now you see everything in the clear, so to speak. If one of the components show an Excel error (like the cell divides by 0 for its result), then you have a culprit. With luck, just one culprit.

This is often a problem when building a spreadsheet as one makes a test change, then realizes another and another are needed to do the test, and so on generating several branchings of work, but cannot find the path back to the good starting point to make the several different changes needed (so instead of incorporating the branchings, one ends up crushing a couple or more into each other in weird ways) and this often leads to real mismatches in cell addresses used like the T9 and Key!$M$14 seemingly mismatched addresses. But just as that apparent mismatch might well be a perfect match instead, this path might not lead to them. Just often.

However, I'd say that, by FAR, the more common problem is antecedent formulas resulting in errors and so calling upon their cells in dependent formulas leads to error results. Lots of reasons that can happen, but since folks usually experience that problems with formulas are construction problems, folks seldom look back to the actual cells called upon. Especially when the first use worked nicely and it's only some of the "copied and pasted down" formulas that result in errors.

So however you do it, you must pick one of the failure results and look at EVERY component cell addressed no matter whether you "know" one or more of them "just can't" be pushing forward an error.

**One thing I forgot to mention is that I set up the formula, down to sheet names having sheets and so on, and it works PERFECTLY. Until I create an error condition in one of the referenced cells. So working as constructed, and giving a correct result for both TRUE and FALSE branchings of your `IF()` is tested — in a careful setup that has no errors in the referenced cells. Put an error in any of them though and it steps back out to the `IFERROR()` result.**

Answer (score 0):

I assume the formula in A18 is referring to T18 (the formula shown uses T9). You might want to change IF(T9<>"" for IF(ISBLANK(T9). <>"" only gives you a TRUE if there is a space there. The screen cap below shows similar results with the formula detail and refenced cell contents

[image]

Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried the `ISBLANK` version that you suggested. The error still populates. The same thing is happening for the `$G9<>"New Phase"` This should eliminate the formula from running for those cells, but it still is. It just seems like all of the conditions in the statement are not being checked. See screenshot in my question. `IFERROR(IF(AND($T9-TODAY()>=Key!$N$14,$T9-TODAY()<=Key!$M$14,$AA9<>"Complete",$G9<>"New Phase",ISBLANK($T9)),Key!$L$11,""),"Error-MUC-Video")`

Comment: I also tried: `NOT(ISBLANK($T9))`